# Rails scope not displaying correct information - Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would just like to understand rails scopes. Any good explanation would be helpful.

- I am trying to display only users who have resumes that have employments
- I used a scope to try and display this:

  ```
  scope :resumes_with_employments, -> {
    where("id in (select resume_id from employments)")
  }
  ```
- I have 2 users. They both have a resume with employments but yet only one user is being displayed.

models

```
user.rb
has_one :resume

resume.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :employments

employment.rb
belongs_to :resume
```

schema

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",
  t.string   "firstname"
  t.string   "lastname"
  t.string   "city"
end

create_table "resumes", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "address"
  t.string   "postcode"
  t.text     "summary"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "employments", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "companyname"
  t.date     "datestart"
  t.date     "dateend"
  t.integer  "resume_id"
  t.string   "employer_name"
  t.string   "employer_tel"
  t.string   "employer_address"
  t.string   "employer_location"
  t.string   "employer_city"
  t.string   "employer_postcode"
  t.string   "employer_email"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope :resumes_with_employments, -> {
  where("id in (select resume_id from employments)")
}
```

would scope the query to users which have an `id` that matches a `resume_id` from the `employments` table. Since the `resume_id` has nothing to do with the user's `id` this scope doesn't return useful results.

I would use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations) in this case, because it translates to a `INNER JOIN` in SQL:

```
# in models/user.rb
scope :resumes_with_employments, -> { joins(resume: :employments) }
```

The nested `INNER JOIN` ensures that only users are return that have a resume that has at least one employment. Since resumes might have multiple employments and the nature of `INNER JOIN` you will need to use `uniq` to exclude duplicates like this:

```
User.resumes_with_employments.uniq
```

Or when you want to count uniq users with that scope:

```
User.resumes_with_employments.distinct.count(:id)
```

Comment: thanks @spickermann i get this error that i do not quite understand `SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" INNER JOIN "resumes" ON "resumes"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "employments" ON "employments"."resume_id" = "resumes"."id" WHERE (id in (select user_id from resumes))` will have a look into it again

Comment: oh i see -  i have this method that is trying to do a count which is creating the error `<%= pluralize(@users.resumes_with_employments.count, 'jobseeker') %>`

Comment: @ARTLoe I updated my answer to address the Exception.

Comment: awesome! this has resolved a lot of similar SQL query issues i had with the app.....wish i could "UP" your answer more than once. thank you once again!